# HTML + Javascript - I can either move or resize multiple div elements but not both at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

My ultimate goal is to create a webpage that has at least 4 different windows that are resizable and movable.  Each window will eventually contain graphs or charts. But I am not there yet.  Currently, I am trying to simply get a template working with just text.  I can add the rest later.

The code below is intended to create two elements that can be moved and resized.   In the BODY of the HTML there are two div sections.  Each creates an element.  One is labelled 'Window Number One' and the other is originally labelled 'Window Number Two'.

If I give both of these divs id='mydiv', both elements will resize, but only window number one will move, meaning the javascript is not being triggered for the second div instance?

If I make the second occurrence of the div id=mydiv2, both elements will move, but only the first will resize, meaning the CSS is not be evaluated correctly for the second div element?

How can I fix this code so ALL of my divs are both movable and resizable?  Remember the ultimate goal is to have 4+ windows, so please call out anything I need to keep in mind as I scale this up.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mydiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>

<h1>Draggable and Resizable DIV Element</h1>


<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Window</p>
  <p>Number</p>
  <p>One</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv2">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Window</p>
  <p>Number</p>
  <p>Two</p>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
dragElement2(document.getElementById("mydiv2"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change `dragElement2` method to `dragElement2`.

If I give both of these divs id='mydiv', both elements will resize, but only window number one will move, meaning the javascript is not being triggered for the second div instance?

because of this line `if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header"))` for second div the condition is **mydiv2header** is false. in order to fix this create separate style for **mydiv2header** and  set **mydiv2header** id for second div
`

If I make the second occurrence of the div id=mydiv2, both elements will move, but only the first will resize, meaning the CSS is not be evaluated correctly for the second div element?

if you fix the first issue it will works.

The following code working fine for me.

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv2"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mydiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

#mydiv2header {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Draggable and Resizable DIV Element</h1>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Window</p>
  <p>Number</p>
  <p>One</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv2">
  <div id="mydiv2header">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Window</p>
  <p>Number</p>
  <p>Two</p>
</div>
```